# "unknown column in field list" error when passing custom string into MariaDB/MySQL C connector API function

Tags: mysql, c, database, mariadb, c-strings

I am trying to make a function which requests the user to enter a new username and password, which then get stored in a MySQL/MariaDB database. I used strcat_s() and strcpy_s() to concatenate strings together to then get passed as a MySQL/MariaDB query in the C API. However, the result is an Unkown column 'foo' in 'field list' error. How can I fix this error? Below is my code.

```
void NEW_PLAYER(MYSQL *con)
{
    const char  *NAME = "foo";
    const char *PASSWORD = "bar";
    char ch = NULL;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    printf("%s\n", NAME);
    printf("%s\n", PASSWORD);
    char TEMP[150];
    char str1[] = "INSERT INTO PLAYERS VALUES(";
    strcpy_s(TEMP, str1);
    strcat_s(TEMP, NAME);
    strcat_s(TEMP, ", ");
    strcat_s(TEMP, PASSWORD);
    strcat_s(TEMP, " ,0, 0, 0, 0)");
    printf("%s", TEMP);
    // inserting null character at end
    if (mysql_query(con, TEMP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

[Here are my results from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShA5P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings must be quote, so you must quote **'foo'** and **'bar'** like this:

```
const char  *NAME = "'foo'";
const char *PASSWORD = "'bar'";
```